# How to check background image

Tags: android, image, background

I have a few buttons in my application that can have different background images.
Now, at the `OnClick` function, I need to check if the Background Image is the image name "williboese" in drawable.

I tried like this:

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //b.setBackgroundColor(R.color.redwue);
            count++;
            if(arg0.getResources().equals(R.drawable.williboese)){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "heeeee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I know at this moment that `b` has this background image but the Toast isn´t shown. What do I make wrong?

Comment: When setting the resource set the tag for the button and check the tag instead

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use tags like this:

```
btn.setTag(R.drawable.williboese);
```

then compare with

```
view.getTag().equals(R.drawable.williboese);
```

because R.drawable is a primitive, this code won't work exactly but you get the idea...

What's wrong with your code is that you are comparing the resource ID of the drawable to the "resources" object of the view. You could try:

```
arg0.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.williboese).equals(arg0.getBackground())
```

Comment: you cannot compare getResources().getDrawable() with other drawable, since getDrawable gets a drawable object for the given resource, but it is not always the same object. Even if the content is the same, probably the instance will be a diferent one. Drawable inherits directly from  Object, and it doesnt has a custom implementation of the equals method, so the comparations are made by the reference, and this wont be the expected behavior.

Comment: you are right that drawable does not implement equals, however Resources uses a caching method for drawables so the object returned for the comparison may not be the same if the cache was purged. I have not tested. However, Resources caching uses a WeakReference and while the button object is using the reference to the original drawable, the drawable should not recycle and the comparison should be valid for the life of the object and the simple case described, but the full extent of code is not available...

Comment: i +1 in your comment since it has good information. Anyways i wouldnt rely on this since is not something we can be totally sure of, and i guess also is not the approach with the best performance. I'd prefer for sure the setTag aproach :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to compare `Resources` with `int` which will be never `true`...

and this trick may help you..

When setting the background resource id, set the that ID as tag for the `View`.

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.williboese);
b.setTag(R.drawable.williboese);
```

and in `OnClickListener` you can check which is the current background drawable...

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int resId = (Integer) view.getTag();
        if(resId == R.drawable.williboese) {
            // background is R.drawable.williboese image
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

getResources doesnt return what you think, as you can see in the source of the function

```
private final Resources mResources;

public View(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mResources = context != null ? context.getResources() : null;
    ...
}

public Resources getResources() {
    return mResources;
}
```

it just returns the same as context.getResources(), an abject for accesing the resources in the app.

You cannot retrieve the id of the background of a view. You will have to save it elsewhere. For that you can use the setTag function of the view, where you can save anything that you can retrieve later. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.williboese);
b.setTag(R.drawable.williboese);
```

and then in the listener you compare

```
        Integer i = (Integer) view.getTag();

        if(i!= null && i == R.drawable.williboese) {
        }
```